# rxjs: merge 2 streams, complete stream when a specific input emits

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I'm writing an Angular app and setting up a system where an NGRX effect will request data to a service.

Underlyingly, this service will do two things:

- Check local cache (sqlite) for the requested data, and
- Contact the API to get the most up to date data

I would like to define an observable response of this service which would emit either only the API's response (in case it was first/local cache miss) or local and then API in that order. I've visualised these 2 scenarios below:

**Scenario 1 (API is first/cache miss)**

```
API   ---1
CACHE ---------2
MERGE ---1
```

**Scenario 2 (Cache hit)**

```
API   ---------1
CACHE ---2
MERGE ---2-----1
```

I'm thinking of creating a Subject, then firing off both calls and completing the Subject when the API responds (either successfully or with an error).

Pseudo code:

```js
const subject = new Subject();

this.cache.getData().then(res => subject.next(res)).catch(err => subject.error(err));
this.api.getData().then(res => subject.next(res)).catch(err => subject.error(err)).finally(() => subject.complete());

return subject.asObservable();
```

But I'm wondering if there's a cleaner solution to what I'm trying to achieve here? Any input greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think what you're after is `concat`. No need for a subject here. `concat(this.cache.getData(), this.api.getData())` and you're done

Comment: It sounds like both the api call and cache calls are async, and he wants to fire them both at the same time.  Keeping the cache emission if it occurs before the api emission.

Comment: @BizzyBob that's correct, thanks for clarifying my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to fire two calls, A) API, B) Cache.  If A returns first emit that result, but not response from B. If B returns first, emit that, but then also emit response from A when it arrives.

Essentially, you always want response from A.  You only want response from B if it is received before A.

If that's the case you could define two source observables and `merge` them.

```js
private apiData$ = defer(() => this.api.getData()).pipe(share());

private cachedData$ = defer(() => this.cache.getData()).pipe(
  filter(existing => !!existing),
  takeUntil(apiData$)
);

data$ = merge(this.cachedData$, this.apiData$);
```

Here we use [`defer`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/defer) to turn your Promise into Observable upon subscription.

`apiData$` is using [`share()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/share) because we are going to end up with two subscriptions and we don't want fire separate calls for each subscription.

`cachedData$` uses [`filter`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/filter) to suppress emissions you don't want (*when data doesn't exist in cache*).

[`takeUntil`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/takeUntil) is used to complete the `cachedData$` observable when `api$` emits any value, therefore `cachedData$` will never emit after `apiData$`

Finally, [`merge`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge) is used to combine both sources into a single observable, so `data$` will emit whenever either source emits.

---

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76463539?devtoolsHeight=100&devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts).

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm and was a lot cleaner than my approach. Just out of curiosity: I'm tracking the connection state, in case the user is offline I don't want to try calling the API. Would you simply tackle this by checking this before doing the merge logic (and thus returning immediately `from(this.cache.getData())` in that case or is it possible to incorporate that in the logic of your answer? I currently fixed it with an if statement beforehand

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76463539-gdpgzh?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=90) would work: `data$ = isOnline$.pipe(switchMap(isOnline => isOnline ? cachedThenApiData$ : cachedData$));`